# Getting the sum and average in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the sum and average of the last column.In my code it wont get the correct value if the table has one,two and three rows.This works only on table with 4 rows.I know something wrong with my code but i cant figure it out how the loop works within .each function.

**Important note:this runs with keyup event to update table data.Its not just a display.To be exact it is an update form.**

**Desired output**

```
Item  | value1 | value 2 | value3 |value 4 | Average 
 01        90      88       87      80        82.25

Total average   82.25     result of 82.25/1 number of row

if two rows

Item  | value1 | value 2 | value3 |value 4 | Average 
 01       90      88       87      80        82.25
 02       80      85       86      84        83.75

    Total average   83     result of (82.25+83.75)/2 number of rows
```

But the result comes out with multiple loops

```
Here is the console.log(totalAverage)
86.25
176
264.75
353.5
442.25
86.25
176
264.75
353.5
442.25
```

Problem:How to suppress or skip this unnecessary values.I only need the 86.25 to display in total-ave.Note: this is only single row right now and have already incountered this miscaculation, how much more if the table has multiple rows then?

**Html**

```
<tr>
 <th colspan="12"><h4>Card</h4></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th colspan="3">Subjects</th>
  <th colspan="2">First Grading</th>
 <th colspan="2">Second Grading</th>
  <th colspan="2">Third Grading</th>
  <th colspan="2">Fourth Grading</th>
  <th>Average</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>   
  <tbody>
 @foreach($update_card['AllGrade'] as $subject)
   {!! Form::hidden('grade_id[]',$subject['grade_id']) !!} 
<tr>
 <th colspan="3">{!! $subject->subject !!}</th>
 <td colspan="2">{!! Form::text('term_1[]',$subject->term_1,['class'=>'form-control','name[]'=>'term_1','id[]'=>'term_1','value'=>'0']) !!}</td>
 <td colspan="2">{!! Form::text('term_2[]',$subject->term_2,['class'=>'form-control','name[]'=>'term_2','id[]'=>'term_2','value'=>'0']) !!}</td>
<td colspan="2">{!! Form::text('term_3[]',$subject->term_3,['class'=>'form-control','name[]'=>'term_3','id[]'=>'term_4','value'=>'0']) !!}</td>
 <td colspan="2">{!! Form::text('term_4[]',$subject->term_4,['class'=>'form-control','name[]'=>'term_4','id[]'=>'term_4','value'=>'0']) !!}</td>
 <td colspan="2" class="average" id="average" value="0"> Average</td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
 <tr>
 <th colspan="11">Total Average:</th>
   <th>{!! Form::text('scholar_GPA',$update_card->scholar_GPA,['class'=>'form-control total-ave','name' => 'total-ave','id' => 'total-ave','value' => '0']) !!}</th>
 </tr>
```

**Javascript snippet**

```
$("input").on("keyup", function(){
 $("tbody tr").each(function() {
    var col=1;
    var tr =1;
    var t = 0;
    var a = 0;

 $(this).children('td').not(':last').each(function () {
 var number = ($(this).children('input').length == 0) ? $(this).html() : $(this).children('input').first().val();
                   // console.log(number);
                   // console.log(col);
                    t += parseInt(number);
                   // console.log(t);

                    a = t/col;
                    col++;

          });
           $(this).children('td').last().html(a);//last td of the  row
          // console.log(a);
           col=1;      
           tr++;


});
    calcTotalave();

    });

        // calculate total average
        function calcTotalave() {
            var totalAve = 0;
            var tot=0;
            var c = 2;
            var count =0;
            $( ".average" ).each(function() {
               // console.log($(this).html());

                var thisAve = parseFloat($(this).html());

                if(!thisAve || thisAve === NaN || thisAve == "") {
                    thisAve = 0;
                }


                totalAve += thisAve;  
                   //alert('count'+thisAve+totalAve); 
                   console.log(totalAve); 

                count++;

            });
                c++;
                totalAve = totalAve/c;
               // console.log(totalAve);

                $("#total-ave").val(totalAve);


        }
```

Comment: Are you calling `calcTotalave` repeatedly?

Comment: We need to see your markup too. Toss it in a jsFiddle with all the parts.

Comment: c++ is outside to loop... Amd you start it at 2??

Comment: I'm kind of flying blind here, but to calculate the total average, you're dividing by 'c' which is initially set to 2 and then incremented.  Seems like you'd want to divide by 'count', not 'c'.

Comment: @epascarello - Sir its 2 because in my other item it has 4 rows.This .each(function() loops 5 times.It it because of the number of columns?So,what im thinking 2 is for c 1,3 == c 2,4==c 3 and 5==c 4.Its like totalAve/c or totalAve/4.But when the table has one,two or three,im already lost in handling the loop.

Comment: @DevendraLattu - Sir in this case,i only click ones or enter a value in the text box with keyup event.

Comment: @BradBales - Sir please read my explaination to epascarello.

Comment: @DevendraLattu - This is an update form, so all input fields are editable.Key up should works in all the fields that updates both the average and Total average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**: fiddle below with comments, press space-bar to run, based around the below function.
the fiddle is made to cycle through and calc cells by row, so no `.average` class required. You will need to adapt it for your html table layouts as per your database output.

```
calcTotalave();

});

    // calculate total average
    function calcTotalave() {
        var totalAve = 0;

        $( ".average" ).each(function() {

            var thisAve = parseFloat($(this).text()) || 0; // always return a number

            totalAve += thisAve; 

        });

        var Aver = totalAve / $('.average').length;  
        console.log(totalAve); 

        $("#total-ave").text(Aver);    
    }
```

instead of classing each cell as `.average` you could use the selector to target all the cells `td` of a given row:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
    calTotalAverages(); // the magic and collect the total average
});

function calTotalAverages(){
  var SumAve = 0, nums = 0; // to collect total averages and the number of rows
  $('tr').each(function(i) {
    if (i > 0) { // ignore the first row
      var $this = $(this);
      SumAve += calcRowAve($this); // add up the returned averages and run the function
      nums ++; // count the rows
    }
  }); // cycle through each row

  var sum = (SumAve / nums);
  $('#total-ave').text(sum.toFixed(2)); // display the total average
  
  return sum; // return the total average
}

// calculate total average
function calcRowAve(targetRow) {
  var totalAve = 0,
    targetCells = targetRow.children(),
    targLength = targetCells.length - 2; // total number of values in a row

  targetCells.each(function(i) {
    if (i > 0 && i <= targLength) {
      var thisAve = parseFloat($('input',this).val()) || parseFloat($(this).text()) || 0; // always return a number
      totalAve += thisAve;
    } // check to ignore the first cell and the last

  });

  var Aver = totalAve / targLength; // get the average
  targetCells.last().text(Aver); // update the last cell of the row
  return Aver;  // return the average for this row
}
```

```css
#total-ave {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2em;
  top: 8em;
}

input{
  width: 5em;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>item 1</th>
    <th>value 1</th>
    <th>value 2</th>
    <th>value 3</th>
    <th>value 4</th>
    <th>average</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>88</td>
    <td>87</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>85</td>
    <td>86</td>
    <td>84</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input type='number'></td>
    <td><input type='number'></td>
    <td><input type='number'></td>
    <td><input type='number'></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id='total-ave'></div>
```

Comment: Sir just updated with my real view page.My table here is a sample.The display of the average is in the last column or td of the row.The Total average is in the next row.

Comment: Sir Sam, I'd tried your code already but the result is in correct.In this single row, the value of Average is supposedly the same with the Total Average except if it has multiple rows.

Comment: My code has input with keyup event.How to put the keyup event here Sir?The purpose here if there is any changes because this is an update form.I'm kinda confuse on how to integrate it.Thank you.

Comment: UPDATED: I've renamed the main functions for clarity, and added further comments. There is a keyup function added. press Spacebar to run.

Comment: Sir if i add an input text field inside td of all column values from 1-4, do it change the value of average?I need the single keyup that acts the action in any text field every time I change its value.As Im said, this is an update form wherein i could change values.Why you are using spacebar here instead of input field?

Comment: Final update. For future questions please provide a working code snippet (inline jsfiddle) of your problem to help people to help you. For input field changes I recommend `.change(func...` instead of `.keyup(func...` and to get the value of an input field you should use `.val()` instead of `.html(`

Comment: Sir I had to modify your fiddle with this http://stackoverflow.com/q/43690782/7928374