# Calculating total average in javascript with keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lacking function in my app using laravel that calculates the total average. Since it needs javascript, I had trouble with and now simplied the table with `foreach` before into this static values but since I have script for *average*, now I need a the function for *total average*.

Hope all could assist me with what I've started. Thank you in advance.

```js
$("input").on("keyup", function() {

  $("tbody tr").each(function() {
    var col = 1;
    var tr = 1;
    var t = 0;
    var a = 0;

    $(this).children('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function() {

      var number = ($(this).children('input').length == 0) ? $(this).html() : $(this).children('input').first().val();

      t += parseInt(number);
      a = t / col;
      col++;

    });
    $(this).children('td').last().html(a);

    col = 1;
    tr++;


  });
  //getTotalave();

});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>score 1</th>
        <th>score 2</th>
        <th>score 3</th>
        <th>score 4</th>
        <th>average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>student1</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1" value="85"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2" value="86"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s3" value="84"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s4" value="81"></td>
        <td class="ave" value="0">84</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>student2</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1" value="88"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2" value="80"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s3" value="84"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s4" value="85"></td>
        <td class="ave" value="0">84.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>student3</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1" value="86"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2" value="86"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s3" value="87"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s4" value="90"></td>
        <td class="ave" value="0">87.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>student4</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1" value="85"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2" value="80"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s3" value="89"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s4" value="90"></td>
        <td class="ave" value="0">86</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Total Average</th>
        <td class="tave" value="">85.375</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In my actual table, there is a foreach loop because the data is coming from the database.In this post, I only have 3 rows with static values just to simplify the snippet.Here is a link of my original post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668776/getting-the-sum-and-average-in-javascript/43668896?noredirect=1#comment74427731_43668896

Comment: So keep a running total with all the values and divide at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a unique class name for the total:

```js
$("input").on("keyup", function() {
  var tAv = 0,
    tRo = 0;
  $("tbody tr").not(':last').each(function() {
    var col = 0,
      t = 0; // starting counters
    tRo++;
    $(this).children('td').not(':first').not(':last').each(function() {

      t += parseFloat($('input', this).val()) || 0;
      col++;

    });
    var rAv = t / col; // row average
    tAv += rAv; // increment average
    $('td', this).last().text(rAv.toFixed(2)); // row average display
  });
  $('.tave').text((tAv / tRo).toFixed(2)); // final average
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Grade</th>
        <th>score 1</th>
        <th>score 2</th>
        <th>score 3</th>
        <th>score 4</th>
        <th>average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>student1</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1" value="85"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2" value="86"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s3" value="84"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s4" value="81"></td>
        <td class="ave" value="0">84</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>student2</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1" value="88"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2" value="80"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s3" value="84"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s4" value="85"></td>
        <td class="ave" value="0">84.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>student3</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1" value="86"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2" value="86"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s3" value="87"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s4" value="90"></td>
        <td class="ave" value="0">87.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>student4</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s1" value="85"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s2" value="80"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s3" value="89"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="s4" value="90"></td>
        <td class="ave" value="0">86</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Total Average</th>
        <td class="tave" value="">85.375</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sir,Why is that the values of average are 60 plus something instead of 80 plus something?

Comment: some of your initial counters should have started at 0 instead of 1, this was casing greater than necessary divisions

Comment: Thanks Sir! This is what I've been looking for since my other last post and hope i could integrate it my app without more manipulation around ROWs and TDs. Good job!